# Passing URL parameter for report in web portal

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there anyway to pass in a filter parameter for report from Web Portal Link?
ReportServer = SSRS Web Service
Reports = SSRS Web Portal

I know there is a way to call it from report server e.g:

```
<host>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fAnnual+Report%2fstore&rs:Command=Render&StoreId=2
```

but is there anyway to do it from web portal? something like this

```
<host>/Reports/report/Annual%20Report/store&StoreId=2
```

Since I'd like to keep the top bar navigation

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "report server" and "web portal". All reports are callable via URL (including adding parameters). There's a whole guide to doing this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs

Comment: I meant, if you take a look at the link you gave me, there is also the web portal, where you can view, search report, etc.
using report server I would not get the top bar navigation like in the above picture.

Comment: I think _"No"_ , check my answer

Comment: Hello Harts, did you find any kind of Workaround for this problem in the last 3 years? I'm currently trying to achieve the same thing, as a disappearing navigation confuses most of our users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is ***NO***, we can't.
In order to [pass parameters with URL in SSRS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-reporting-services/) , we have to do it via reportserver URL not via Report Manger URL.. 
[image]
[image]

---

And normally, we would call it *Report Manager*, what you mentioned as *web-portal* : )